# What is the variable for the location of santa for the santa tracker API?

Tags: python

I tried finding Santa's current location, but the location variable only contained my current location. I want to be able to find Santa's current location on the Api, https://santa-api.appspot.com/info?client=web&language=en&fingerprint=&routeOffset=0&streamOffset=0.

I tried using the location variable and I got my current location.

```
import requests
santaApi = requests.get("https://santa-api.appspot.com/info?client=web&language=en&fingerprint=&routeOffset=0&streamOffset=0").json()
formatted_data = santaApi["location"]
print(formatted_data)
```

This is my code and when I ran it I got my current location.

I expected to get Santa's location but I got mine instead.

Please help solve this frustrating problem!

Comment: Perhaps Santa is currently at your home? :)

Comment: {
"status": "OK",
"language": "en",
"now": 1589251795344,
"location": "-33.868820,151.209295",
"switchOff": false
} // I get MLC centre in Sydney, probably my ISP location.

Comment: Yep, wondering how to get santa's current location.

Comment: Santa is presently at the North Pole preparing for the busy holiday season

Comment: Yes, I would like a variable in the api to get that location.